# Rails - accepts_nested_attributes_for and presence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application I have a simple relationship where a **user** that has many **events**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, foreign_key: 'created_by', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end


class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'created_by', inverse_of: :events
  validates :created_by, presence: true
end
```

When I am trying to create a user alongside with some events I am getting a validation error *"Companies.created by can't be blank"*.

My params hash looks like that:

```
{"user"=>{"events_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"disney show"}]}}
```

When I remove `validates :created_by, presence: true` everything works as expected. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add your controller function from where you are rendering this form.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify explicitly bi-directional associations in your User model using `inverse_of:` :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :events, foreign_key: 'created_by', inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end
```

And your `Event` record will be created with present foreign key pointing to `User`.